# jQuery toggle() not working properly

Tags: jquery

I would like to toggle between 2 divs using jquery. One toggle is a google maps map, the other one a simple list (just html)

So in my page I have

```
<div id="toggleDiv">
    <a href="#" id="btnClick"><button>Toggle</button></a>
    <div class="toggle" id="map"></div>
    <div class="toggle" id="list" style="display:none">HTML stuff</div>
</div>
```

Then the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnClick').click(function() {
        $('#toggleDiv > .toggle').toggle();
    });
});
```

It does not toggle.... I thought it was because of the map, which is loaded by another script, but i tried also without it, with another simple HTML div...

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wp1xbonp/

Comment: Your code works as it should work. On click, it will show/hide .toggle div?

Comment: What errors do you get in your console? Also, your HTML is invalid. You can't have a button as a child of an anchor.

Comment: Is your `toggleDiv` dynamically loaded?

Comment: Works as coded.  https://plnkr.co/edit/r3IUrdKvDinDqL4MwRTj?p=preview

Comment: event delegation is needed i guess

Comment: no error in console, simply nothing happens, i will have always the map div visible and `toggleDiv` it's static inside a jsp page

Comment: How much of the above code is being loaded by another script? The click handler might not be binding to the element on page load if elements are loaded after. Try binding the click to the document?

Comment: I guess you are making very silly mistake. Try to see whether you have referenced the script file properly

Comment: It would be better if you provide a jsfiddle or plunkr

Comment: Added fiddle link, thanks

Comment: It works in your fiddle. But you needed to add jQuery using the cogs button: https://jsfiddle.net/wp1xbonp/3/

Comment: Yes, it works, so I think the problem may be the google map...

Comment: As for the map, It used to be the map would not load into a hidden div: you had to show the div and then call the API code to load the map. I don't know if that's still true, but something else to keep in mind.